# How do I temporarily store form data on a user's computer from sessionstorage?

Tags: javascript, solid-js

I created a registration form in my solid-js application. I would like that after the submission of the form, that the values ​​entered disappear from the input fields of the form but are kept on the browser of the user temporarily (until the shutdown of the computer) in order to be able to get these values ​​later in other code files. For this, I therefore decided to use sessionstorage and wrote the following code in my `useSendVerificationEmail.jsx` file:

```
const [form, setForm] = createStore({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    gender: "",
  });

    sessionStorage.setItem('firstName',form.firstName)
    sessionStorage.setItem('lastName',form.lastName)
    sessionStorage.setItem('email',form.email)
    sessionStorage.setItem('password',form.password)
    sessionStorage.setItem('gender',form.gender)
```

And in order to use these values ​​in other files, I do this in another file of my projet more precisely in my `useResendEmail.jsx` file so the previous code and the following code come from two different files:

```
    const firstName = sessionStorage.getItem('firstName')
    const lastName = sessionStorage.getItem('lastName')
    const email = sessionStorage.getItem('email')
    const password = sessionStorage.getItem('password')
    const gender = sessionStorage.getItem('gender')
```

because I think that since the values ​​are kept on the user's computer, it is possible to directly access the value of these variables. But the values ​​of the specified keys are not returned by sessionstorage . I looked on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109801/how-to-display-the-preview-of-information-entered-by-user-using-vue-js) and also on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69882163/store-temporarily-data-on-browser) but nothing. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update local storage values in SolidJS using hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030144/how-to-update-local-storage-values-in-solidjs-using-hooks)

Comment: I'm not good at it and don't work in Typescript so I don't quite understand the answers to this question. Thanks!

Comment: I added more informations in my question. Thanks and good evening !

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the glue code between the form field and the local storage. Here is a simple example using a signal but you can change it to use a store:

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, onMount } from "solid-js";

function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = createSignal('');

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    if (event) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('some-value', event.target.value);
    }
  };

  onMount(() => {
    const someValue = sessionStorage.getItem("some-value") || '';
    setVal(someValue);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={val()} type="text" onInput={handleInput} />
    </div>
  );
}

render(App, document.getElementById("app"));
```

We restore the stored value using `onMount` hook which runs after the element is mounted.

We store the new value whenever the input field is updated using `onInput` handler. Unlike React, Solid keeps close to HTML standards and does not use `onChange`.

One more thing, sessionStorage is short-lived and destroyed when the window or tab closes, so the stored value can not survive a refresh. Alternatively you can use localStorage which keeps values until they are cleared manually.

Comment: I don't quite understand your code and my problem is not storing values ​​from sessionStorage but rather accessing stored values ​​from other files in my project.

Comment: I added more informations in my question. Thanks and good evening!

Comment: Code is simple, store the updated value when user types in the input field and restore it when the page is reloaded or refresh it.